# PHP error, concatenation in array() in member initialiser

Tags: php, arrays, string, properties, concatenation

I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
public $arr = array('email' => 'admin@' . str_replace('http://', '', SERVER_ROOT));

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
```

Am I being really stupid? Surely I can concatenate strings here?

This is a variable declared in a class.

Comment: Did you try it with " double quotes? `"admin@"`

Comment: @Martin no that's not the problem

Comment: funny thing is, it works here (w/out class) >> http://ideone.com/tq0CK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize class attributes with an expression. You have to do that in the constructor or use a fixed value, like a regular string.

Comment: Really? Well I never knew that before. Cheers @xato :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an error, you can't initialize a property like this

> Properties
>
> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
>   include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constantvalue--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time andmust not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**